# Using dblookupcombox for filtering

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010

I'm using this code to filter my table with dblookupCombobox:

```
ADOTable1.Filtered:=False;
ADOTable1.Filter:='Section=' + ADOTable2.FieldByName('Section').AsString;
ADOTable1.Filtered:=True;
```

but it raises this exception:

> the arguments are of the wrong type outside the allowed limits.

Where is the problem please?

Comment: What is the value of ADOTable1.Filter when you set Filtered to True and what is the DDL definition of ADOTable1?   Do you still get the error if you do `ADOTable1.Filter  :=  'Section=' + QuotedStr(ADOTable2.FieldByName('Section').AsString) ?

Comment: @MartynA Thank you man, it works, i just add +QuotedStr, Thank you so much...

Comment: Good.  I've posted what I said as an answer and included an explanation of what the problem was.  When you get a moment, please be so kind as to "accept" the answer by clicking the "tick" icon on its left - that way, future readers will know that it answers your q.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are getting happens because of this:

Suppose the value of AdoTable2.FieldByName('Section').AsString is `SomeValue`.  Then, the value you assign to AdoTable1.Filter is

```
Section = SomeValue
```

AdoTable1 tries to interpret SomeValue as a field name, but this fails because AdoTable1 does not have a field of that name.

To overcome the problem, you simply need to surround SomeValue in the Filter expression in quotes.  Delphi has a utility function `QuotedStr` which will do that for you (and correctly deal with the situation where the string passed into it contains embedded quotes (e.g. where the value is a name like O'Brien').

So replace your current assignment of the filter by:

```
ADOTable1.Filter := 'Section=' + QuotedStr(ADOTable2.FieldByName('Section').AsString);
```